# SQL Server where condition based on selected case column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am selecting columns based on case statement and want to filter with where clause based on returned column in case statement.

```
Select 
    case 
       when UpdatedDate is not null 
          then UpdatedDate 
       when InsertedDate is not null 
          then InsertedDate 
       else VisitedDate 
    end
From 
    tbl_UserTracking
where 
    [UpdatedDate/InsertedDate/VisitedDate(based on case)] between date1 and date2
```

Comment: It would probably be better for all if you had not simplified the question. If each if those date columns are from different tables, and those values are potentially NULL because of outer joins then what one does in the join logic and/or where clause will depend on the data and the required result. Please reconsider the question providing a more realistic version of the we uery. Also orovide sample data and the expected result. There are guides available on how to ask questions so that you get better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM
(   SELECT case when UpdatedDate is not null then UpdatedDate 
                when InsertedDate is not null then InsertedDate 
                else VisitedDate END AS DateColumn
    FROM tbl_UserTracking
) T
WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Comment: it will not give performance issue ? because huge data will be returned from inner query with out date filtering.

Comment: *Probably* not.  I'm guessing you'd have either a table scan or index scan for this query regardless.  Run the query analyzer and peek at the query plan if you're worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(UpdatedDate, InsertedDate, VisitedDate) AS DateColumn
FROM tbl_UserTracking
WHERE COALESCE(UpdatedDate, InsertedDate, VisitedDate) BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

Comment: Columns are from different tables and case conditions are also different, i just simplified conditions..

Comment: @Gopinath You can have COALESCE(T1.UpdatedDate, T3.InsertedDate, T8.VisitedDate)

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()`.  This simplifies the `where` clause:

```
Select coalesce(UpdatedDate, InsertedDate, VisitedDate)
From tbl_UserTracking
where coalesce(UpdatedDate, InsertedDate, VisitedDate) between date1 and date2;
```

If you want to define a variable, you can use a CTE or subquery.  I like to point out lateral joins, which in SQL Server use the `apply` keyword:

```
Select v.thedate
From tbl_UserTracking t outer apply
     (values (coalesce(UpdatedDate, InsertedDate, VisitedDate))
     ) v(thedate)
where v.thedate between date1 and date2;
```